golang copy of parent process is not able to make https/tls calls and gets "tls: failed to verify certificate"
I'm working on https://github.com/NorseGaud/go-daemon and I'm not able to run http GET calls inside of the child processes. I don't know enough about golang and os.Process.
I'm using macOS.
When I run "go run examples/cmd/gd-signal-handling/signal-handling.go", which is just doing a simple httpClient.Do in the child, I see:
2024/04/05 17:45:33 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
2024/04/05 17:45:33 daemon started
1
2024/04/05 17:45:34 error making GET request to google.com err Get "https://google.com": tls: failed to verify certificate: SecPolicyCreateSSL error: 0

Yet it works if I run the same httpClient.Do in the main func.
I then quit the process with "go run examples/cmd/gd-signal-handling/signal-handling.go -s quit".
Would someone familiar with both golang and processes be able to explain to me why this isn't possible?

What go version do you use? It seems the bug of Go at MacOS. I reffered this page https://github.com/golang/go/issues/61000

I was on 1.21.7, upgrade to 1.22.2 just now and it's still happening. Thanks for the link! I'll take a look.

Thank you for your confirmation, @NorseGuard.
I found the issue similar with yours here. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/61000
It seems this problem is reproduced when using the relative path only at MacOS and has not been solved completely by Apple.

I was hoping you'd post an answer so I could upvote it :)

@NorseGuard It motivates me to do better! Thanks

Using absolute path stopped working in 14.5 macOS. I can't use go run at all to test the app.
