Get "https://google.com": tls: failed to verify certificate: SecPolicyCreateSSL error: 0 when running in child
Here is the main.go you can reproduce with using go run main.go:
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

// Mark of daemon process - system environment variable _GO_DAEMON=1
const (
    MARK_NAME  = "_GO_DAEMON"
    MARK_VALUE = "1"
)

// Default file permissions for log and pid files.
const FILE_PERM = os.FileMode(0640)

// WasReborn returns true in child process (daemon) and false in parent process.
func WasReborn() bool {
    return os.Getenv(MARK_NAME) == MARK_VALUE
}

// A Context describes daemon context.
type Context struct {
    // If PidFileName is non-empty, parent process will try to create and lock
    // pid file with given name. Child process writes process id to file.
    PidFileName string
    // Permissions for new pid file.
    PidFilePerm os.FileMode

    // If LogFileName is non-empty, parent process will create file with given name
    // and will link to fd 2 (stderr) for child process.
    LogFileName string
    // Permissions for new log file.
    LogFilePerm os.FileMode

    // If WorkDir is non-empty, the child changes into the directory before
    // creating the process.
    WorkDir string
    // If Chroot is non-empty, the child changes root directory
    Chroot string

    // If Env is non-nil, it gives the environment variables for the
    // daemon-process in the form returned by os.Environ.
    // If it is nil, the result of os.Environ will be used.
    Env []string
    // If Args is non-nil, it gives the command-line args for the
    // daemon-process. If it is nil, the result of os.Args will be used.
    Args []string

    // Credential holds user and group identities to be assumed by a daemon-process.
    Credential *syscall.Credential
    // If Umask is non-zero, the daemon-process call Umask() func with given value.
    Umask int

    // Struct contains only serializable public fields (!!!)
    abspath  string
    logFile  *os.File
    nullFile *os.File

    rpipe, wpipe *os.File
}

func (d *Context) SetLogFile(fd *os.File) {
    d.logFile = fd
}

func (d *Context) openFiles() (err error) {
    if d.PidFilePerm == 0 {
        d.PidFilePerm = FILE_PERM
    }
    if d.LogFilePerm == 0 {
        d.LogFilePerm = FILE_PERM
    }

    if d.nullFile, err = os.Open(os.DevNull); err != nil {
        return
    }

    if len(d.LogFileName) > 0 {
        if d.LogFileName == "/dev/stdout" {
            d.logFile = os.Stdout
        } else if d.LogFileName == "/dev/stderr" {
            d.logFile = os.Stderr
        } else if d.logFile, err = os.OpenFile(d.LogFileName,
            os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, d.LogFilePerm); err != nil {
            return
        }
    }

    d.rpipe, d.wpipe, err = os.Pipe()
    return
}

func (d *Context) closeFiles() (err error) {
    fmt.Println("closeFiles")
    cl := func(file **os.File) {
        if *file != nil {
            (*file).Close()
            *file = nil
        }
    }
    cl(&d.rpipe)
    cl(&d.wpipe)
    cl(&d.logFile)
    cl(&d.nullFile)
    return
}

func (d *Context) prepareEnv() (err error) {
    if d.abspath, err = os.Executable(); err != nil {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("abspath", d.abspath)

    if len(d.Args) == 0 {
        d.Args = os.Args
    }

    mark := fmt.Sprintf("%s=%s", MARK_NAME, MARK_VALUE)
    if len(d.Env) == 0 {
        d.Env = os.Environ()
    }
    d.Env = append(d.Env, mark)

    return
}

func (d *Context) files() (f []*os.File) {
    log := d.nullFile
    if d.logFile != nil {
        log = d.logFile
    }

    f = []*os.File{
        d.rpipe,    // (0) stdin
        log,        // (1) stdout
        log,        // (2) stderr
        d.nullFile, // (3) dup on fd 0 after initialization
    }

    return
}

func (d *Context) reborn() (child *os.Process, err error) {
    if !WasReborn() {
        child, err = d.parent()
    } else {
        err = d.child()
    }
    return
}

func (d *Context) parent() (child *os.Process, err error) {
    if err = d.prepareEnv(); err != nil {
        return
    }

    defer d.closeFiles()
    if err = d.openFiles(); err != nil {
        return
    }

    attr := &os.ProcAttr{
        Dir:   d.WorkDir,
        Env:   d.Env,
        Files: d.files(),
        Sys:   &syscall.SysProcAttr{},
    }

    fmt.Println("parent startProcess")
    if child, err = os.StartProcess(d.abspath, d.Args, attr); err != nil {
        return
    }

    d.rpipe.Close()
    encoder := json.NewEncoder(d.wpipe)
    err = encoder.Encode(d)

    fmt.Println("parent done")

    // if this sleep keeps the parent around, it will work.
    // time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)

    return
}

func (d *Context) child() (err error) {

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(os.Stdin)
    if err = decoder.Decode(d); err != nil {
        return
    }

    return
}

func main() {

    daemonContext := &Context{
        PidFileName: "test.pid",
        PidFilePerm: 0644,
        LogFileName: "test.log",
        LogFilePerm: 0640,
        WorkDir:     "/tmp",
        Umask:       027,
        Args:        []string{"SecPolicyCreateSSL"},
    }

    d, err := daemonContext.reborn()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    if d != nil { // return the parent process since it's now forked into a child
        return
    }

    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)

    fmt.Println("doing get...")
    resp, err := http.Get("https://google.com")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(body)[:100])

    return
}


Once ran, you'll see in test.log:
doing get...
2024/07/23 13:07:21 Get "https://google.com": tls: failed to verify certificate: SecPolicyCreateSSL error: 0

Now under the parent function, uncomment // time.Sleep(3 * time.Second) and then run again.
You should then see it working:
doing get...
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"><head><meta content

It seems as if the parent closing too soon is causing the child to not have, what I can only guess, is the proper environment available on linux and macOS.
Though, I'm not entirely sure why. I've tried digging into this as low level as I am aware of and nothing is clicking for me as to the cause. Does anyone know why this isn't possible?
I would like the parent to be able to exit well before the child, so that I can use the golang binary as a controller for the daemon/service. But I also can't guarantee that https calls will happen before the parent exits.

What you present doesn't compile:  You use github.com/norsegaud/go-daemon in your code, but have github.com/sevlyar/go-daemon with a replace in your go.mod. It seems during shotgun debugging things broke, and this is basically a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78282560/golang-copy-of-parent-process-is-not-able-to-make-https-tls-calls-and-gets-tls

@eik you'll need to clone the go-daemon repo locally so the replace works and you can look at the way go-daemon works. I've fixed the main.go, regardless.

Additionally, this is not a duplicate of that other issue as the solution for that other issue is not solving the error in this one.

How about using Cmd.Start with os.Executable instead? Your package is screwing something up, and I don't know if you'll find someone willing to debug it.

Does it only happen with forked proc?

I've updated the main.go to be library-less. This should help clarify exactly what the problem is that I'm seeing.
